# How to integrate Skype for Business functionalities in a WPF application

Tags: .net, wpf, skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

We are creating a WPF application that is controlled through Kinect gestures. One of the functionalities it has to implement is Skype for Business integration and I am completely confused by all the [sdks](http://dev.office.com/skype/sdks) Microsoft offers for this.

We need to integrate the following into our wpf application:

- starting, ending and refusing an audio or video call
- detecting when the user has an incoming call
- detecting when the ongoing call has been hung up

We can either swap focus to the actual Skype for Business window or integrate the controls into our wpf application, but I'm not sure what to use for the integration.

What I've mostly looked at is the [Lync 2013 Client SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj933180.aspx), but it seems that it has problems with Skype for Business 2016 and also it looks kind of outdated with its pre requirement for silverlight controls and Visual Studio 2012.

I'm completely confused over how to use the [UCMA 5.0 SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn454984(v=office.16).aspx) and whether I can even use it in a WPF application since I've found no examples regarding that.

So I decided to ask the community for a recommendation. What is currently the best way to integrate Skype for Business audio/video call functionality into a WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use Lync Client SDK 2013. It is compatible with Skype for Business 2016. We have used it in our project successfully (with VS 2013 and CS 2015).
Can you mention what are the issues you faced while using it?

On UCMA 5.0, it is really a server side SDK. It is very strong in terms of functionality. You can create meeting, invite participant, listen to conversations etc. using the SDK.

Alternatively, you may like to explore [Skype for Business Web SDK](https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk). It is also quite rich in features. Since, it is a web SDK you may need to put it under a user control for your WPF application.

Comment: UCMA, as of 5.0, does not support Video or Application/Desktop Sharing.  You are still stuck with Lync SDK if you want to do those things.